# Google Chrome white flash

Tags: google-chrome

It has been asked times and times again, has anyone found a fix for this issue? The problem is easy to replicate, when opening a new tab or clicking a link, a brief white background is shown before Chrome starts loading the actual content.

Comment: What? You mean that blank white canvas that has yet-to-be filled with loaded content? Simply get a faster internet and/or computer that loads all  webpages as fast you click them... How is this a **programming question**??

Comment: are you using direction: rtl or jquery?